# Facebook wall post is appending link with `accessToken`

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook's Javascript SDK to post to a users wall.

The code which performs the actual post is:

`linkUrl` is a fully qualified domain name.

```
          FB.ui({
                method: "feed",
                link:linkUrl,
                picture:imgUrl,
                name:title,
                "description":description,
                actions: [
                    {name: linkUrl, link: linkUrl}
                ]
            },
            function (response) {
                if (response != null || response != undefined) {
                    fadeOutAlert = true;
                    self.fbMessageLabel.innerHTML = "Thank you, your Facebook post has been successful!";
                    self.fbMessageDialog.dialog("open");
                };
            });
```

The post works perfectly well and appears on the users wall, however the `link` has Facebooks `access_token` appended to it. So rather than linking to `my.website.com` it's actually linking to `my.website.com/#access_token=aReallyLongAccessToken&expires_in=5684`

Is there a way to prevent the `access_token` from being appended to the `link`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bah.. I have been playing with this for DAYS now.. and just figured it out.

Ok, so for others that may have the same problem..

You need to go to the settings on the app and select the `Permissions` options.

Then set `Authenticated Referrals` to disabled, as in the image below. This will stop Facebook adding the `access_token` to your links.

[image]